# Python: getters and setters for lists of lists

Tags: python

The following code

```
def set_item(myMap, x, y, elem):
    myMap[x][y] = elem
    return myMap


def get_item(myMap, x, y):
    item = myMap[x][y]
    return item

myMap = [[".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","."],["#","#","#",".",".",".",".",".",".","."],[".","#","#","#",".",".",".",".",".","."],[".",".","#","#","#",".",".",".",".","."]]
print(set_item(myMap,0,6,"#"))
print(get_item(myMap,2,3)
```

does nothing and sometimes returns errors. I would like to be able to easily set and get individual values from maps (lists of lists).

Comment: Move myMap to the top of the code. And change your myMap parameter name to something else.

Comment: What do you mean 'does nothing' ? Do you not get any output, no errors, or does it simply not update the element in your list?

Comment: @The.B `myMap` is a local function argument. The fact that the global variable and the argument have the same name is irrelevant.

Comment: It does not update the element in the list.

Comment: The code runs fine for me with the expected results. What output do you get and how is it different from what you expect?

Comment: I never name the parameters as the globals. It’s confusing.

Comment: @The.B that's not relevant to the OP's post either.

Comment: @Sidoniux your code runs fine for me too.

Comment: Maybe it is because I work in Spyder (I found out it works in Visual Studio but not in Spyder). I need Spyder, because it can work with numpy, while Visual Studio cannot.

Comment: It should run the same in any python environment. I think it's more likely that there's some small overlooked difference from the code you ran in spyder.

Comment: I work with literally the same file in both environments. Spyder is just strange and returns different errors for this code every time.

Comment: Why won't you show us those errors? And you're clearly not running the above code, as it's missing a `)` at the end and thus gets the same syntax error every single time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except for you last instruction that misses a closed bracket and would throw a `SyntaxError`, I don't see anything wrong in your code.

However you didn't catch `IndexError` (*out of range*) inside your functions, so you should be careful about `x` and `y` when you call them, and remember that lists are indexed from 0, which is a pretty common oversight mistake.

If you're not even messing up `myMap` with some different data types inside it, you should be able to run that code safely in any environment.

Answer (score 0):

Your functions work fine.  See the before and after lists below when you insert the word 'new.'  However, to improve the code, note that setter functions usually don't return anything.  They just set the value for a variable or, in this case, mutate a list.  This will become more apparent when you start writing classes.  For now, just remove the return statement from your setter function.  It will work like this:

```
def set_item(myMap, x, y, elem):
    myMap[x][y] = elem

def get_item(myMap, x, y):
    item = myMap[x][y]
    return item

myMap = [[".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","."],["#","#","#",".",".",".",".",".",".","."],[".","#","#","#",".",".",".",".",".","."],[".",".","#","#","#",".",".",".",".","."]]

print(f'Original:\n{myMap}')
set_item(myMap,0,6,"new")

print(f'final:\n{myMap}')
print(f'Item at (2,3): {get_item(myMap,2,3)}')

#output:
Original:
[['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['#', '#', '#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '#', '#', '#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '#', '#', '#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
final:
[['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'new', '.', '.', '.'], ['#', '#', '#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '#', '#', '#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '#', '#', '#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
Item at (2,3): #
```